# "Посмотри фильм() и всё поймёшь". Ставится ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

**Посмотри фильм() и всё поймёшь.**

Необходима ли здесь запятая?
Мне кажется — да, т.к. можно поставить общее для предложений слово:
[Ты] посмотри фильм и всё поймёшь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то, "посмотри" и "поймешь" - это однородные сказуемые, соединенные одиночным союзом "и", поэтому запятая не нужна. Правда, здесь возможно интонационное тире, так как между словами, составляющими это предложение есть обстоятельственный оттенок значения (если посмотришь фильм, то все поймешь)

Comment: Один глагол стоит в повелительном наклонении, другой - в будущем времени. Нельзя их считать однородными членами предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что это ССП с двумя определенно-личными предложениями РАЗНОЙ СТРУКТУРЫ, поэтому запятая ставится: Посмотри фильм, и все поймешь.

К примеру, У Розенталя: "Постояли, потолковали и пошли назад" - это не однородные сказуемые, а неопределенно-личные предложения (Здесь запятая перед И  не ставится ввиду их семантической и грамматической однородности).

Определение структуры предложения подстановкой слова "ты" некорректна, так как вид предложения при этом меняется.